# How to remove unwanted character from fullcalendar week view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I am using JQuery fullcalendar plugin. On week view I am seeing some wired symbol instead of "-". See attached image

[image]

I want to remove this character.

My document is already having following tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Any suggestion is most welcomed.

Comment: Maybe html-file has another encoding?

Comment: That should work. Check the actual encoding of the HTML file. Try the calendar in a new file. I assume the desktop environment and browser you're viewing it in supports UTF8? It would be unusual not to, but you have to rule everything out.

Comment: Where is your code?